# React RTK Query with Socket.io connection behaves strangely during data update

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, multiplayer, rtk-query

I'm making a basic multiplayer game using React with RTK Query and Socket.io. I followed the RTK Query documentation for subscription case where they made a chat app.
Basically the only change I make is instead of appending the new data to the end of an array, I'd use a single object instead I'd like to update.
But when I try to use an object, it stays {}.

The annoying thing is if I use the array solution it works just fine. (So just using array[0] as the draft)

So basically the only differencies are:

1. `initGame: builder.query<ClientGame[],...` -> `initGame: builder.query<ClientGame,...`
2. `queryFn: () => ({ data: [] })` -> `queryFn: () => ({ data: {} as ClientGame })`
3. `draft[0] = newGameState` -> `draft = newGameState`

**Works fine:**

```
export const menuApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'menuApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/'
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Menu'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        initGame: builder.query<ClientGame[], void>({
            queryFn: () => ({ data: [] }),
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                _, // arg
                { updateCachedData, cacheEntryRemoved }
            ) {

                const socket = getSocket();
                try {
                    socket.on(ServerEvents.InitGame, (newGameState: any) => {
                        updateCachedData((draft) => {
                            draft[0] = newGameState
                        })
                    })
```

**Won't return with actual data:**

```
export const menuApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'menuApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/'
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Menu'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        initGame: builder.query<ClientGame, void>({
            queryFn: () => ({ data: {} as ClientGame }),
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                _, // arg
                { updateCachedData, cacheEntryRemoved }
            ) {

                const socket = getSocket();
                try {
                    socket.on(ServerEvents.InitGame, (newGameState: any) => {
                        updateCachedData((draft) => {
                            draft = newGameState
                        })
                    })
```

Vs code even thinks that draft is unused [image: Image from vscode displaying unused variable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the answer. Sending the recived data directly is the key.

```
socket.on(ServerEvents.InitGame, (newGameState: ClientGame) => {
  updateCachedData(() => {
    return newGameState;
  })
})

// Or using the spread operator to update partially
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  return { result: { ...draft.result, stage: newStage.result } }
});
```